# Add new property in object recursively

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have a recursive array with same structure  of objects and it contains `name` property. My requirement is to add new property `id` along with name in recursive array of objects

below is my sample array

```
[
    {
        "children": [
            {
                "children": [
                    {
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "children": [],
                                "name": "ID01",
                                "type": "Under"
                            },
                            {
                                "children": [],
                                "name": "ID02",
                                "type": "Under"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name": "httpgateway",
                        "type": "Gut"
                    },
                    {
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "children": [],
                                "name": "mock1",
                                "type": "Under"
                            },
                            {
                                "children": [],
                                "name": "mock2",
                                "type": "Under"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name": "mock",
                        "type": "Gut"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "23131",
                "type": "SEV"
            }
        ],
        "name": "integration",
        "type": "DataCenter"
    },
    {
        "children": [
            {
                "children": [
                    {
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "children": [],
                                "name": "data1",
                                "type": "Under"
                            },
                            {
                                "children": [],
                                "name": "data12",
                                "type": "Under"
                            },
                            {
                                "children": [],
                                "name": "data13",
                                "type": "Under"
                            },
                            {
                                "children": [],
                                "name": "data14",
                                "type": "Under"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name": "Gut1",
                        "type": "Gut"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "213213",
                "type": "SEV"
            }
        ],
        "name": "dev",
        "type": "dt"
    }
]
```

I need Id property along with name as belo

```
[
    {
        "children": [
            {
                "children": [
                    {
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "children": [],
                                "name": "ID01",
                                "id": "ID01",
                                "type": "Under"
                            },
                            {
                                "children": [],
                                "name": "ID02",
                                "id": "ID02",
                                "type": "Under"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name": "gate",
                        "id": "gate",
                        "type": "Gut"
                    },
                    {
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "children": [],
                                "name": "mock1",
                                "id": "mock1",
                                "type": "Under"
                            },
                            {
                                "children": [],
                                "name": "mock2",
                                "id": "mock2",
                                "type": "Under"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name": "mock",
                        "name": "id",
                        "type": "Gut"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "23131",
                "id": "23131",
                "type": "SEV"
            }
        ],
        "name": "int",
        "id": "int",
        "type": "dt"
    },
    {
        "children": [
            {
                "children": [
                    {
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "children": [],
                                "name": "data1",
                                "id": "data1",
                                "type": "Under"
                            },
                            {
                                "children": [],
                                "name": "data12",
                                "id": "data12",
                                "type": "Under"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name": "Gut1",
                        "id": "Gut1",
                        "type": "Gut"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "213213",
                "id": "213213",
                "type": "SEV"
            }
        ],
        "name": "dev",
        "id": "dev",
        "type": "dt"
    }
]
```

I have written method to update this but its not working as expected

```
const getTreeItemsFromData = (treeItems) => {
  console.log('---------------------------', treeItems)
  let finalData = []
  return treeItems.map((treeItemData) => {
    let children = undefined;
    if (treeItemData.children && treeItemData.children.length > 0) {
      children = this.getTreeItemsFromData(treeItemData.children);
    }

    let uniqueId = `${treeItemData.name}${Math.floor(Math.random()*(999-100+1)+100)}`;
    finalData.push(treeItemData)
    console.log("-- ------------------", treeItemData)
    
  });
};
```

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/xhd4gufs/

Comment: *its not working as expected* – you should describe the actual and the expected behavior and your attempts to debug if you want some help with debugging at SO

Answer (score 0):

You jus need a function to accept the array and check if the key `children` exists and is array, make changes to it and then recursively call if it has children.

```
const t = [
  {
    "children": [
      {
        "children": [
          {
            "children": [
              {
                "children": [
                  
                ],
                "name": "data1",
                "type": "Under"
              },
              {
                "children": [
                  
                ],
                "name": "data12",
                "type": "Under"
              },
              {
                "children": [
                  
                ],
                "name": "data13",
                "type": "Under"
              },
              {
                "children": [
                  
                ],
                "name": "data14",
                "type": "Under"
              }
            ],
            "name": "Gut1",
            "type": "Gut"
          }
        ],
        "name": "213213",
        "type": "SEV"
      }
    ],
    "name": "dev",
    "type": "dt"
  }
];
function addIdRec(arr){
    arr.forEach(a => {
        if(a.children instanceof Array){
            a.id = a.name;
            if(a.children.length > 0){
                addIdRec(a.children);
            }
        }
        
    })
}
addIdRec(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with a pretty simple recursion:

```js
const addId = (data) => 
  data .map (({name, children, ...rest}) =>
    ({children: addId(children), name, id: name, ...rest})
  )

const data = [{children: [{children: [{children: [{children: [], name: "ID01", type: "Under"}, {children: [], name: "ID02", type: "Under"}], name: "httpgateway", type: "Gut"}, {children: [{children: [], name: "mock1", type: "Under"}, {children: [], name: "mock2", type: "Under"}], name: "mock", type: "Gut"}], name: "23131", type: "SEV"}], name: "integration", type: "DataCenter"}, {children: [{children: [{children: [{children: [], name: "data1", type: "Under"}, {children: [], name: "data12", type: "Under"}, {children: [], name: "data13", type: "Under"}, {children: [], name: "data14", type: "Under"}], name: "Gut1", type: "Gut"}], name: "213213", type: "SEV"}], name: "dev", type: "dt"}]

console .log (addId (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We simply clone the node, adding an `id` property to match the `name` one and recur on the `children` property.